# UILabel Autoshrink does not work with Dynamic Text and special character

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uilabel, nsattributedstring, dynamic-text

I am using iOS 7`s new Dynamic Text feature for the subtitle of a table view row. I have set the UILabel in IB as follows:

[image]

This is how I set the contents of the UILabel in code:

```
NSAttributedString *checkmarkAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString 
      alloc]initWithString:@"☑"];
[detailAttributedString appendAttributedString:checkmarkAttributedString];
```

This is the result which is not autoshrinked correctly (the font size should be scaled down and the "..." avoided):

[image]

How can I get autoshrink to work?

It seems that it works correctly when I do not add the special character (checkmark) at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but it looks like the Minimum Font Scale has a comma in it. Shouldn't it be 0.4?

Otherwise try this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
cell.detailLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Comment: The comma is correct (in my region). However, I found out that I am setting the font to the old font styles in code manually. Do you know how to set the font to one of the new Dynamic Text font styles?

Comment: Use a system font. Those should support Dynamic Text. So like [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in iOS 6 it works fine for iOS 7,
In iOS 6 if the text is multilines then it will not shrink.